# Bootstrap brand isn't centering vertically in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm having trouble centering my branding logo vertically in the center.  As of right now my rendered html looks like this:

```
   <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>
        <img alt="brand" height="200%" src="/assets/logo.png" />
```

If I don't set the height to a size, it will be the full size of the png.  But my branding isn't vertically center with the rest of my navbar.

My css for the navbar-brand looks like this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
 }
```

What do I need in my css to make this center with the navbar?

This is the full render of the navbar, pulled right from bootstrap docs.

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default' role='navigation'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <button class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
        <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
      </button>
      <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>
        <img alt="brand" height="200%" src="/assets/logo.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='active'>
          <a href='#'>Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class='dropdown'>
          <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
            Dropdown
            <span class='caret'></span>
          </a>
          <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
            <li>
              <a href='#'>Action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='#'>Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='#'>Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class='divider'></li>
            <li>
              <a href='#'>Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li class='divider'></li>
            <li>
              <a href='#'>One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class='navbar-form navbar-left' role='search'>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <input class='form-control' placeholder='Search' type='text'>
        </div>
        <button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class='dropdown'>
          <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
            Dropdown
            <span class='caret'></span>
          </a>
          <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
            <li>
              <a href='#'>Action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='#'>Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='#'>Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class='divider'></li>
            <li>
              <a href='#'>Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: Please post the complete HTML of your header/navbar.

Comment: As mentioned in http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image , you may need to futz with the padding etc. yourself.

Comment: Updated with the rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use absolute positioning:

```
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: // half the width of your img
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that CSS aligns the logo horizontally instead of vertically os the OP asked for?